# Sending Scope variable as a pointer and altering it outside the controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a $scope variable form that contains the fields device and codes.

```
    $scope.form = {

        device: '',

        codes: "PlaceHolder_Data"

    };
```

I want to pass this to a function that alters it. For example i want foo($scope.form) to alter the codes. 
The way I do it is:

```
var foo = function (obj) {
     obj.codes = "new data";
}
```

This works for regular javascript objects but doesn't work here! foo is an async function though. I have also registered a $watch on $scope.form.codes to console.log any changes but that doesn't get called at all.

Comment: Please show us how you're calling the `foo` function.

Comment: I just do foo($scope.form);

Comment: From the controller, it should work. From a template, `foo` is undefined (since all the variables used in a template are just attributes of `$scope`), so you should add it to your `$scope` before.

Comment: I'm calling it in the controller!

Comment: Then I'm unable to reproduce your problem. Please provide a [MCV exemple](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the object into a factory, then changing it with a service.

```
//create the function to apply to form
app.service('exService', function(){ 
       this.exFunction(form){
          //do stuff to form
       return // create new stuff
        };
});

//apply service to the form object
app.factory('exFactory', ['exService', function(exService) {
   var exForm = {
       device: '',
       codes: "PlaceHolder_Data"
   };
   var o = exService.exFunction(exForm) //applying service to form
   return o; 
}]);
```

after that inject the 'exFactory' factory into your controller like so

```
app.controller('exController',['$scope', 'exFactory', function($scope, exFactory){
      //Do suff with exFactory
}]);
```